# Order of features for gridsearch and model fitting

Tags: random-forest, scikit-learn, hyperparameter, ensemble-learning, boosting

Assuming that the same columns (i.e., features) are used for hyperparameter tuning and model fitting, and ensemble models are used for modeling (e.g., Random forest or XGboost), then does the order of columns used during the hyperparameter tuning process should be identical to the order of columns used when fitting the model based on the best hyperparameters?

I am using sklearn's make_column_transformer functions in my CV pipeline for the hyperparameter tuning. Unfortunately, this function modifies the order of provided columns when setting the remainder argument to 'passthrough'. Should I ensure that when fitting the model the same order of columns is preserved, or the order does not matter as long as I am using the same features.